# Is there a package for XYZ-files for chemical use in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

Is there a magic tool for LaTeX to create figures from [XYZ-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format)?

Since I don't know which package I should use for it, my MWE is, well, minimal:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Even if there is such tool you need to specify and decide what is a good perspective to show your structure. What you can do is use Xmakemol (http://www.nongnu.org/xmakemol/), interactively find a good perspective, export/print to EPS, (convert to PDF) and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Is there any news here?